# Cannot insert NULL value into column error

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I have a issue where I want to update a column in a table and with a trigger to update same column but in another table. It says I cannot insert NULL but I can't seem to understand from where it gets that NULL value. This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Custom_WF_Update_WF_DefinitionSteps_DefinitionId ON WF.Definition 
AFTER UPDATE AS BEGIN 
IF UPDATE(DefinitionId) 
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() < 2 
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE WF.DefinitionSteps NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

    UPDATE WF.DefinitionSteps
    SET DefinitionId =
         (SELECT i.DefinitionId
          FROM inserted i,
               deleted d
          WHERE WF.DefinitionSteps.DefinitionId = d.DefinitionId
               AND i.oldPkCol = d.DefinitionId)
    WHERE WF.DefinitionSteps.DefinitionId IN
          (SELECT DefinitionId FROM deleted)

     ALTER TABLE WF.DefinitionSteps CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL 
END 
END
```

This update statement works just fine:

```
UPDATE [CCHMergeIntermediate].[WF].[Definition] 
SET DefinitionId = source.DefinitionId + 445 
FROM [CCHMergeIntermediate].[WF].[Definition] source
```

But this one fails:

```
UPDATE [CCHMergeIntermediate].[WF].[Definition] 
SET DefinitionId = target.DefinitionId 
FROM [CCHMergeIntermediate].[WF].[Definition] source 
INNER JOIN [centralq3].[WF].[Definition] target 
ON (((source.Name = target.Name) OR (source.Name IS NULL AND target.Name IS NULL)))
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Custom_WF_Update_WF_DefinitionSteps_DefinitionId, Line 7
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DefinitionId', table 'CCHMergeIntermediate.WF.DefinitionSteps'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

If I do a select instead of the update statement, like this:

```
SELECT source.DefinitionId, target.DefinitionId
FROM [CCHMergeIntermediate].[WF].[Definition] source 
INNER JOIN [centralq3].[WF].[Definition] target 
ON (((source.Name = target.Name) OR (source.Name IS NULL AND target.Name IS NULL)))
```

I get this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cZsM.png (sorry for external link, I don't have enaugh reputation to post image here )

What am I doing wrong? What I don't see? What am I missing..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the trigger at the condition. I modified the second where from `i.oldPkCol = d.DefinitionId` to `i.oldPkCol = **d.oldPkCol**` and it worked.

```
UPDATE WF.DefinitionSteps
SET DefinitionId =
     (SELECT i.DefinitionId
      FROM inserted i,
           deleted d
      WHERE WF.DefinitionSteps.DefinitionId = d.DefinitionId
           AND i.oldPkCol = **d.oldPkCol**)
WHERE WF.DefinitionSteps.DefinitionId IN
      (SELECT DefinitionId FROM deleted)
```